# How to get the name of the materials associated to the faces of Rooms in Revit

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I want to write a Macro in Autodesk Revit for getting all the materials associated to the faces of my rooms and then write them as values for predefined Shared Parameters. Is there a way to achieve this with C#?
Also I'd like to have the walls faces according to the cardinal position (North, South, West, East).
Any hint about it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest raising separate threads for different questions.

Regarding the wall faces facing cardinal positions, please refer to the `DirectionCalculation` `FindSouthFacing` Revit SDK sample.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Revit Lookup to research the right way to write a filteredelementcollector.